# Python - Transform dataframe and slicing

Tags: python, pandas

I have attached a screenshot to help explain. I have a dataframe pulled from cleveland heart dataset that takes 76 columns and puts them into 7 columns and wraps the additional columns into the next row. I am trying to figure out how to get that dataframe into a readable format as shown in the dataframe on the right-hand side.

[image]

The variable xyz will always be the same but the other letter variables I have listed will be different. I thought I could use data.loc[:, :'xyz'] to start but I'm not sure where to go from here:

```
data = pd.read_csv("../resources/cleveland.data")
data.loc[:, :'xyz']
```

I will then have to go from there and assign column names to these variables. Surprisingly, the train, test, validate portion of this will be much easier once I get this sorted out. Thanks in advance for the help. (I'm a rookie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Input data**

```
1   a   b   c
d   xyz 2   e
f   g   h   xyz
3   i   j   k
```

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# The initial data doesn't contain header so set header to None
df = pd.read_csv("../resources/cleveland.data", header=None)
cols = df.columns.tolist()

# Reset the index to get the line number in the durty file
df = df.reset_index()

# After having melt the df, you can filter the df in order to have every values in one column.
# Those values are in the right order
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['index'], value_vars=cols)
df = df.sort_values(by=['index', 'variable'])

# Then you can set the line number
df['line'] = np.where(df.value == 'xyz', 1, np.nan)
df.line = df.line.cumsum()
df.line = df.line.bfill()

# If the file doesn't end with 'xyz', we have to set the line number to df.line.max() + 1
df.loc[df.line.isna(), 'line'] = df.line.max() + 1
df.line = df.line.ffill()

# We can set the column names as interger with a groupby cumsum
df['one'] = 1
df['col_name'] = df.groupby(['line'])['one'].cumsum()
df['col_name'] = "col_" + df['col_name'].astype('str')

# Then we can pivot the table
df = df[['value', 'line', 'col_name']]
df = df.pivot(index='line', columns='col_name', values='value')
print(df)
```

**Output Data**

```
col_name col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5 col_6
line
1.0          1     a     b     c     d   xyz
2.0          2     e     f     g     h   xyz
3.0          3     i     j     k   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: This looks helpful, however, a,b,c,d,e,f, g,h, i, j, k xyz would all be on one row and then we have to parse out the next line. I was always looking to stop the line at xyz and start the new line at the position after that. Then from there stop at xyz and start new line at the position after that. These positions won't always be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy` for this, after forming one big array of all values. A combination of `np.array_split` + `np.where` to split on the indices after `xyz`:

#### Sample Data: `test.csv`

```
1,a,b,c,d,e,f,g
h,i,j,k,xyz,2,a,b
c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
k,xyz
```

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None).values.ravel()

pd.DataFrame(np.array_split(arr, np.where(arr == 'xyz')[0]+1)).dropna(how='all')
```

#### Output:

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11   12
0  1  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  xyz
1  2  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  xyz
```

From @CharlesR data

```
   0  1  2  3     4     5
0  1  a  b  c     d   xyz
1  2  e  f  g     h   xyz
2  3  i  j  k  None  None
```